How to click on a chevron for 'more results' with selenium?
I am scraping a web page with Selenium searching for results. This is working fine, I do get the results I want, but not all results, only 12 out of hundreds.
To get the additional results, I must click on a 'chevron' (>). And keep doing that on every page that appears next.
But I just cannot get hold of that chevron to click on. A push in the right direction would be appreciated.
This is the URL I am trying to scrape:
text
And the section I am interested in, with the link from the chevron for "Go to next page"

I have been on this for days now, and have tried everything I could find online, using XPATH and CSS Selector, but for some reason none of these work. I keep getting this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a aria-label="Go to next page" rel="next" class="sc-1xjnf9n-1 sc-1xjnf9n-3 jDxtQi cuAvlD" href="/house-and-pet-sitting-assignments/?q=eyJmaWx0ZX

This is what I have tried so far:
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[aria-label="Go to next page"]'))).click()

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);"), WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, next_page_xpath)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();"), WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_page_xpath)))

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-1xjnf9n-3').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-1xjnf9n-3'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_page_xpath))).click()

next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_page_xpath)))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
    next_button.click()

next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_page_xpath)))
    for _ in range(3):
        try:
            next_button.click()
            break  # Successful click, exit the loop

        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            time.sleep(2)  # Wait for a while before retrying

Any guidance is greatly appreciated, so I can learn from this.

You can get the results from the api directly:
import requests
import json

query = {
    "filters": {
        "activeMembership": True,
        "pets": [
            {"type": "dog", "exclude": True},
            {"type": "cat", "exclude": False},
            {"type": "reptile", "exclude": True},
            {"type": "horse", "exclude": True},
            {"type": "fish", "exclude": True},
            {"type": "bird", "exclude": True},
            {"type": "poultry", "exclude": True},
            {"type": "farm animal", "exclude": True},
            {"type": "small pet", "exclude": True}
        ],
        "geoHierarchy": {"countrySlug": "united-kingdom"}
    },
    "facets": [],
    "sort": [{"function": {"name": "POPULAR_NEW_SITS_WITH_PAUSED", "order": "asc"}}],
    "page": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 100
} 


headers = {
  'api-version': '2021-10-26',
  'referer': 'https://www.trustedhousesitters.com/',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


# Get the first page (100 results)
url = 'https://www.trustedhousesitters.com/api/v3/search/listings/'
response = requests.get(url, params={"query": json.dumps(query)}, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
results = data.get('results')
total = data.get('total')


'''
# Get the remaining results:
while len(results) < total:
    query['page'] += 1
    response = requests.get(url, params={"query": json.dumps(query)}, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    results.extend(data.get('results'))
'''
print(results)


Edit:
Here's a query with all the filters enabled, you can find more details if you inspect the network tab
{
  "filters": {
    "activeMembership": True,
    "assignments": {
      "dateFrom": "2024-07-27",
      "dateTo": "2024-12-30",
      "reviewing": True,
      "confirmed": True,
      "durationInDays": {"minimum": 1, "maximum": 3}
    },
    "pets": [
        {"type": "dog", "exclude": True},
        {"type": "cat", "exclude": False},
        {"type": "reptile", "exclude": True},
        {"type": "horse", "exclude": True},
        {"type": "fish", "exclude": True},
        {"type": "bird", "exclude": True},
        {"type": "poultry", "exclude": True},
        {"type": "farm animal", "exclude": True},
        {"type": "small pet", "exclude": True}
    ],
    "localAttractions": ["beach","city","countryside","mountain"],
    "homeType": ["house", "apartment"],
    "familyFriendly": True,
    "wifiAvailable": ["high speed"],
    "disabledAccess": True,
    "isAccessibleByPublicTransport": True,
    "carIncluded": True,
    "geoHierarchy": {"countrySlug": "united-kingdom"}
  },
  "facets": [],
  "sort": [{"function": {"name": "POPULAR_NEW_SITS_WITH_PAUSED", "order": "asc"}}],
  "page": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 100,
}


Thanks, that works brilliantly! I did not even know that they had an API, how did you find that out? And where did you learn how to construct the query? Can I add more variables, such as dates?

@Stefan just through inspecting the network tab, see the edited answer for the query with dates/duration.

Use this XPath expression:
//li[@data-testid='RouterPagination_next']

Code:
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-testid='RouterPagination_next']"))).click()


I tried that, but still ended up with an error message:
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (589, 490). Other element would receive the click: ...
I don't know what this means, and how to get around it. Do you have ideas?

It means other element is obstructing the view and is not allowing to click on the targeted element. You need to figure out what that obstructing element is and get rid of it. Can you edit the question and share full code so that I can try to reproduce this error?

Thanks, I have found the element that is obstructing it. The 'getting rid of it' is an entirely different matter, any idea how I can do that? I don't get the error when I open the browser fullscreen, then the elements don't overlap. But that's not a very practical solution. I would rather learn how to get rid of the element in front.
